# how to create json array at run-time and add elements to the particular array?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I want to create multiple arrays at the run-time, moreover the program have ability to add the data to the particular array called upon.

```
 button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {

                String productType = txtProductType.getText();
                String model = txtModel.getText();
                String year = txtYear.getText();

                File file1 = new File(FILE_NAME);
                if (file1.length() == 0) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

                    map = new LinkedHashMap(2);

                    map.put("model", model);
                    map.put("year", year);

                    jsonArray.add(map);

                    jsonObject.put(productType, jsonArray);

                    FileWriter file = new FileWriter(FILE_NAME, false);
                    file.append(jsonObject.toString());
                    file.flush();
                    file.close();

                } else {
                    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(FILE_NAME));
                    if (obj == null) {
                        System.out.println("ex");
                    }
                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
                    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get(productType);

                    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();

                    map = new LinkedHashMap(2);
                    map.put("model", model);
                    map.put("year", year);
                    jsonArray.add(map);

                    jo.put(productType, jsonArray);

                    FileWriter file = new FileWriter(FILE_NAME, false);
                    file.append(jo.toString());
                    file.flush();
                    file.close();

                }

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "Data parsed into JSON.", "Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(WriteInJSONGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

    });
```

I have tried above and it is creating the json array and also adding the elements to the called array but only for once, but I want to create a new array whenever user want to add new productType. 
Json output achieved:

```
{"Insight":[{"year":"2019","model":"myc"},{"year":"dgdfg","model":"ii"}]}
```

Json output required:

```
{"Insight":[{"year":"2019","model":"myc"},{"year":"2018","model":"ii"}], "Odyssey":[{"year":"2019","model":"ody"}],"Coupe":[{"year":"2019","model":"cup"},{"year":"2017","model":"cup"}]}
```

Comment: Do you know the Gson library (https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md) from Google? If not, it is worth to read the documentation. Makes life easier if you have to work with JSON.

Comment: Iam using simple json

Comment: SimpleJson ist not maintained anymore since five years (https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple). Think  about using Gson if possible.

Comment: seriously i will go through GSon , as simple json always makes me in trouble. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write back `root` `JSON` node. Name of your root object is `jsonObject` but you write `jo`. Take a look on below example:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(jsonFile));
// root object
JSONObject root = (JSONObject) obj;
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) root.get(productType);
if (jsonArray == null) {
    jsonArray = new JSONArray();
}
Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(2);
map.put("model", "Model");
map.put("year", 2019);
jsonArray.add(map);

root.put(productType, jsonArray);

FileWriter file = new FileWriter(jsonFile, false);
// use root object
file.append(root.toString());
file.flush();
file.close();
```

Comment: Thanks Michał Ziober for the required solution

Answer (score 1):

Since you are reading the entire file into memory, I'm assuming you have enough memory to store all the data you intend on storing.  With that assumption, I think a better and more efficient approach would be to have something like

```
Map<String, List<Map<String,String>>> items = new HashMap<>();
```

Then, for each item that gets added:

```
List<Map<String,String>> list = items.computeIfAbsent(productType, k-> new ArrayList<>());
Map<String,String> newMap = new HashMap<>();
newMap.put("model", model)
newMap.put("year", year);
list.add(newMap);
// convert list to json string and write to file in overwrite mode
```

This will save you the need to read in the file in order to add items, and you can just use the file storage as persistence

Comment: Its works wonderfully with minimum efforts of reading the file, but for the very first time I have to read the file if there exist no data. Though I dont know more about the persistence but seems it is worth using when doing filing and storage.  Thank You aaarbor

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List jsonArray = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        add(jsonArray);
    }
}

private static void add(List jsonArray) throws IOException {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    LinkedHashMap<Object, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(2);
    map.put("model", "myc");
    map.put("year", "2019");

    jsonArray.add(map);
    jsonObject.put("Insight", jsonArray);

    FileWriter file = new FileWriter("test.json", false);
    file.append(jsonObject.toString());
    file.flush();
    file.close();
}
```

}

The output file looks like this

```
{"Insight":[{"model":"myc","year":"2019"},{"model":"myc","year":"2019"},{"model":"myc","year":"2019"},{"model":"myc","year":"2019"},{"model":"myc","year":"2019"}]}
```

Comment: Thanks , its not what i was looking for, but  I got the solution from others responses. thank you